# XPath for node based on the value of another node?

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is my XML:

```
<record>
  <f id="7">South East Asia</f>
  <f id="8">Binondo</f>
  <f id="10">3098</f>
  <f id="11">Manila, Philippines</f>
  <f id="27">Commercial</f>
  <f id="22">Dela Cruz, Anna</f>
  <f id="28">D572307</f>
</record>
```

I want to create an XPath that will return `Dela Cruz Anna` if `record` has a `f` with and `id` of `3098`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//record[f[@id=10]="3098"]/f[@id="22"]/text()
```

will select the text of all `f` elements with `id` attribute values of `22` within all `record` elements with an `f` element that has an `id` attribute value of `3098`,

```
Dela Cruz, Anna
```

as requested.

Comment: Great. Tried it, exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.